# Huygens' principle in Einsteins calculation of deviation of light in Schwarzschild gravitational field

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature, huygens-principle

To calculate the deviation of light in a Schwarzschild gravitational field, Einstein used Huygens' principle. I put here a reference to Einstein's paper [*On the Influence of Gravitation on the Propagation of Light,* Annalen der Physik,35,pp. 898-908, 1911](https://www.relativitycalculator.com/pdfs/On_the_influence_of_Gravitation_on_the_Propagation_of_Light_English.pdf).

My questions are:

1. Is Huygens' principle in general valid in such a curved space time field?
2. If the answer is no, what should I do to get a more accurate value than the one Einstein calculated?